# Different outcome with different conditional distributions in GARCH model (rugarch)

Tags: model-selection, garch

I am using an external regressor in the variance equation of a GARCH model (rugarch). However, the value of the GARCH coefficient is coming out to be zero with a p-value of 1 and the coefficient of external regressor to be significant, when I am using the ged distribution. When I am using the std distribution, the GARCH coefficient remains significant and the external regressor insignificant. Opposite outcome, just by the change of the conditional distribution. My question is how to choose the distribution then? (this is the original post).

I will need to estimate a GARCH model, first without any exogenous variables, 2nd with exogenous variable ex1 and 3rd with exogenous variable ex2. Please note the table below:

Model specs                          AIC using ged      AIC using std
GARCH without exog regressor              2.3743             2.3705
GARCH with 1st exog regressor ex1         2.3746             2.3708
GARCH with 2nd exog regressor ex2         2.3140             2.3689

In the above AIC is lower when using ged for ex2, compared to std. But the problem is that they are all part of the same process, and will need to be estimated simultaneously. Can I select two conditional distributions for estimating the three models of the same process? That is for GARCH without exog regressor I use std, for GARCH with 1st exog regressor ex1, I use std and for GARCH with 2nd exog regressor I use ged.

[image]

Comment: In this case I would tackle the question of model selection independently of the interpretation of the selected model. Thus first select, then interpret. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garch+model-selection) are some related questions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have done that but there is another issue. I estimate 3 models, 1 model without exog regressor & 2 models with exog regressor individually, (using 2 exog regressors). Issue is that the AIC is lower using std for model without exog regressor and one of the exog regressor. In the third model (where 2nd exog regressor is used) AIC is lower when ged is used. How to select in this case?

Comment: Why not select the model with the lowest AIC? You can also check whether the fitted standardized residuals match the assumed distribution reasonably well. If they do not, you will at least be aware of that, even if you select that model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can do that, but the problem is that the associated 2 models (one without exog regressor and one with the 1st exog regressor) have higher AIC values. Its like this: when I run all three models using ged & then compare with the three models using std, I find a discrepancy - the 3rd model using the 2nd exog variable yields higher AIC...I am adding the data, if that is allowed in the next comment section

Comment: Do not post additional information as comments. Rather, edit the original post. Also, I do not really get what your results are and why you find them problematic. Could you show your results in a table or something to make them transparent and easily comparable?

Comment: Thanks I will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such tiny differences between AIC would normally mean all the models are roughly equally good (or equally bad). However, the table contains AIC-per-observation, not AIC, as `rugarch` has got the nomenclature wrong. To obtain the actual AIC, you would have to multiply it by the sample size $T$. If $T$ is 100 or more, the differences are quite salient. There seems to be a clear winner at 2.314.

(I would also check whether the reported AIC-per-observation is has not been multiplied by -1; then the winner would be the highest value, i.e. 2.3746, and it would be not such a clear-cut case unless $T$ is about 666 or more. I use 666 to yield a difference of 2 between the AIC values of the best and the next best model. But according to p. 28 of the [`rugarch` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf), the signs are not mixed up, so then there is no need to multiply by -1.)